# When does a file need to be compiled exactly?

Tags: html, web, build, compilation

This is probably a dumb question, but how do you know when something needs to go through a "build" or be compiled? My understanding of it is that when you code, you are writing source files, when then, in order to be understood by the computer, will need to be compiled to executable files. But then, how come I can just write a index.html and pull it into my browser for it to work? When did the compiling happen in this situation? How does this compare to the compiling that happens when you use build tools like npm?

Comment: html isn't compiled, its a markup language that tells the browser how to display the text

Comment: This depends very much on the language. In some languages like C you need to compile all source files. In other languages like Python the compiler is built into the interpreter and the compilation step is invisible to the programmers. HTML is not really a programming language, but it will still be *compiled* (i.e. translated to an internal form) by the web-browsers.

Comment: so for different web apps, it depends on the language where it gets compiled? if the browser does the compiling, what is the use of build systems like npm? does it just organize the dependencies to tell the browser what needs to be compiled in order for certain modules to work?

Comment: In the context of web-sites, the build step is mainly to verify and to [*minify*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) JavaScript code. The HTML "code" is not involved. Miniofication is also a compilation, as it translates a source language into a destination labnguage (which in both cases is JavaScript). That is basically what a compiler does: Translates a source language to a destination language.

Comment: so the JS code is not being compiled during the build step? it's only compiled when it's being read by the browser, which then sends the code down to be executed by the CPU?

Comment: i had always though compiling meant translating specifically to executables, but destination language is much better. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling means to make a list of machine codes that can be stored and executed by the machine. Browsers do not do that they just parse and execute the language without building a list. (Although often as mentioned in comments for faster execution, code may be compiled on the fly and sent to CPU as machine codes.)

Comment: when the browsers execute the code, what is happening there? doesn't that mean they still have to translate the code somehow and communicate with the cpu for it to show up on your screen? doesn't the communication with the cpu always mean that code has to be compiled at a certain point for the cpu to understand what to do? perhaps a wider question is how does it matter who is "executing" the code? even if it's the browser, doesn't everything in the end indirectly go back to the cpu reading some type of machine language to execute it in order for code to work?

Comment: A little hard for me to explain but basically the fact that it's not stored as a list makes all the difference. The way a browser works is it takes one command at a time, for example draw the string 'hello' and calls an OS function that has already been compiled to draw whatever string sent to it and draw it. Hope it's somewhat clear.